# how can I update appcompat_v7?

Tags: android, upgrade, libraries, android-appcompat

I am developing in Android and after switching to API 22, I began to have errors in my App. Searching on stackoverflow I found the solution, getting the latest version of Appcompat_v7.

How can I proceed? Where I can download the latest version or where I can update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your `Android SdK` and find `SDK manager.exe`, click it and then find the `Extra` in the window opened, and select `Android Support Library` to download it.

After the downloading finished, you will get the latest `v7 support library`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but why the appcompat-v7 version is LOCKED to 26.0.0-alpha1 ??? Impossible to install v27 required by facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import appcompat_v7 into your workspace from your SDK location. Your SDK location may be like this:

```
C:\Users\[Your Name]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\
```